# Create a matrix showing count of occurrences for the combinations

Tags: excel, vba

How do I create a matrix (using VBA) showing count of occurrences from the row data that has 2 columns.
Please see the row data on the left and the result that I need on the right.

[image: Example]

I tried the code from the similar problem that was posted and the solution provide but does not work.

Please see code that I used:
Sub Matrix()

```
Dim dict As Object, k, ar, m, v1, v2
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim lastrow1 As Long, lastrow2 As Long, i As Long, j As Long, x As Long, y As Long
Dim a As String, b As String, c As String

With Sheet3
    lastrow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow1
        a = .Cells(i, "A")
    
        If Not dict.exists(a) Then
            dict.Add a, New Collection
        End If
        
        
        'dict(b).Add a
    Next
End With

With Sheet3
    lastrow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For x = 1 To lastrow2
        b = .Cells(i, "B")
       
        If Not dict.exists(b) Then
            dict.Add b, New Collection
        End If
        'dict(b).Add a
    Next
End With

' results
ar = dict.keys
i = dict.Count
ReDim m(1 To i, 1 To i)
With Sheet4
    For i = 1 To UBound(m)
        ' headers
        .Cells(1, i + 1) = ar(i - 1)
        .Cells(i + 1, 1) = ar(i - 1)
        ' counts
        For j = 1 To UBound(m, 2)
            a = ar(i - 1)
            b = ar(j - 1)
            m(i, j) = 0
            If a <> b Then
                For Each v1 In dict(a)
                   For Each v2 In dict(b)
                       If v1 = v2 Then m(i, j) = m(i, j) + 1
                   Next
                Next
            End If
           .Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = m(i, j)
        Next
    Next
End With


ar = dict.keys
x = dict.Count
ReDim m(1 To x, 1 To x)
With Sheet4
    For x = 1 To UBound(m)
        ' headers
        .Cells(1, x + 1) = ar(x - 1)
        .Cells(x + 1, 1) = ar(x - 1)
        ' counts
        For y = 1 To UBound(m, 2)
            a = ar(x - 1)
            b = ar(y - 1)
            m(x, y) = 0
            If a <> b Then
                For Each v1 In dict(a)
                   For Each v2 In dict(b)
                       If v1 = v2 Then m(x, y) = m(x, y) + 1
                   Next
                Next
            End If
           .Cells(x + 1, y + 1) = m(x, y)
        Next
    Next
End With

MsgBox "Done"
```

End Sub

Thank you for your help.

I am new to creating matrix using VBA hence need your assistance.

Comment: Why VBA and what have you tried? I think you could just use a regular formula.

Comment: Thank you, I am interested with the VBA code for this.

Comment: So it appears you have not attempted anything on your own? If so, please post.  Stack Overflow is not a free coding help website, and based on your username, I'm guessing your question relates to making money. Rather than just ask for free help, make an effort to solve the problem on your own using google an youtube. Then come back with a specific issue. Please read: [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I did try below code, it was related to one of the similar question but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```vb
Sub MatrixCount()
    Const MATRIX_TOPLEFT As String = "E2"            'top-left corner of matrix output
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rw As Range, dictR As Object, dictC As Object
    Dim lkhood, impact, c As Range
    
    Set dictR = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary") 'for tracking row/column offsets
    Set dictC = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set c = ws.Range(MATRIX_TOPLEFT)                 'top-left corner of matrix output
    
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A2:B10").Rows           'loop over the data
        impact = rw.Cells(2).Value
        If Not dictR.exists(impact) Then             'first time for this value?
            dictR.Add impact, dictR.Count + 1        'assign a row offset
            c.Offset(dictR.Count, 0).Value = impact  'add the row header
        End If
        lkhood = rw.Cells(1).Value
        If Not dictC.exists(lkhood) Then
            dictC.Add lkhood, dictC.Count + 1        'assign a column offset
            c.Offset(0, dictC.Count).Value = lkhood  'add the column header
        End If
        
        With c.Offset(dictR(impact), dictC(lkhood))
            .Value = .Value + 1 'increment the value using both offsets
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried and worked as expected, once again, thank you so much!!!